# Synchronous javascript call to block the IHM until process is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, struts2

To begin, i will say that what i am trying to do is to click on an button (that will export an excel so the type of this action is a stream) and while the server is processing i want to block the IHM with an overlay that will display a GIF.

So to do this i used the method "css" of jquery to set the "display" to block (to activate the overlay) and to none (to deactivate it). 
THE PROBLEM is that that does not seem to work cause it activates and the deactivates the overlay instantly (i verified with the debug mode on chrome to see and if i stop IHM right after the .css('display','block') it would freeze the IHM with the settled background + the gif but if i don't set the breakpoint it will bypass it, call the action (with the submit) and remove the background+popup) so this is obviously done async.
I tried to do it in synchronous way with this Ajax call like this but after displaying returning the string result (server side) the page felt in error (i think because it is an stream result) :

```
function exportComplexExcel() {  
    // export excel
        jQuery("#overlayBackground").css('display', 'block'); // displaying the overlay
        jQuery("#overlayPopup").css('display', 'block'); // displaying the popup
        $.ajax({
                    method : "GET",
                    url : "exportExcelMdt.action",
                    traditional : true,
                    async : false,
                    contentType : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                    complete : function(data) {
                        jQuery("#overlayBackground").css('display', 'none'); // displaying the overlay
                        jQuery("#overlayPopup").css('display', 'none'); // displaying the popup
                    }
                });
}
```

This is (in the JSP) the code to do it :

```
function exportComplexExcel() {  
    jQuery("#overlayBackground").css('display', 'block'); // displaying the overlay
    jQuery("#overlayPopup").css('display', 'block'); // displaying the popup

    $("#searchForm").attr("action", "complexExportExcelMdt.action");
    $("#searchForm").submit();

    jQuery("#overlayBackground").css('display', 'none'); // displaying the overlay
    jQuery("#overlayPopup").css('display', 'none'); // displaying the popup
}
```

Here is the use of the method exportExcel() :

```
function insertComplexExcelButtonForExtraction() {
    // creer le nom depuis "#gview_" + l'id de la grid  
    var $btnComplexExcel = $('#gview_resultGrid > div > #btnComplexExcel');

    // Check if object already exists 
    if(!$btnComplexExcel.length) {
        var $a = $('#gview_resultGrid > div > #btnExcel');
        var $newA = $a.clone();

        $newA.attr('style', 'right: 50px; padding-top: 2px;');
        $newA.attr('id', 'btnComplexExcel');
        $newA.children("#searchForm_exportExcelMdt").remove();
        $newA.append($('<input id="searchForm_complexExportExcelMdt" type="image" onclick="exportComplexExcel();" src="/myApp/img/page_white_excel_plus.png" title="<s:text name="myApp.message.js.button.complexExcelExtraction"/>"/>')); 
        $newA.insertAfter($a);
    }
}
```

I know that the code to define the onClick action is weird but it is what it is (meaning old code :D) The method "insertExcelButtonForExtraction" is called in another function that is used in a "onblur" field in a "s:textfield" (i don't think we need to see it).

Here is the css file (or the portion that is called here) :

```
#overlayBackground {
background: #000000;
opacity:0.5;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 10000;
}

#overlayPopup {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 20px solid #DDDDDD;
left: 31%;
padding: 50px;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
top: 28%;
width: 380px;
z-index: 20000;
-moz-border-radius:30px 0;
}
```

Here is the struts action :

I used this code for my action method :

```
@Action(value = "exportExcelMdt", results = {

        @Result(name = "exportExcel", 
                type = "stream", 
              params = { "inputName", "inputStream", 
                       "contentType", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
                "contentDisposition", "attachment;filename=${filename};", 
                        "bufferSize", "1024" }),

        @Result(name = "success", 
                type = ActionSupport.NONE) 
})

public String doExportExcel() {

    Boolean exportPending = (Boolean) this.session.get(EXPORT_EXCEL);
    if (exportPending == null) { // this is used as a semaphore to prevent the user from re-calling the export action (server-side of course)
        try {
            this.session.put(EXPORT_EXCEL, Boolean.TRUE);
            logger.debug("export excel...");
            this.filename = this.getText("myApp.message.mandat.recherche.extraction.filename");
            this.inputStream = this.extractExcel(this.searchResults(false)); // this will just get the related beans and write the excel file using Apache POI
            return "exportExcel";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("export excel erreur...");
        } finally {
            this.session.remove(EXPORT_EXCEL);
        }
    } else {
        //          this.addActionMessage("An export excel is already running !");
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the related struts.xml file :

```xml
<struts>
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/jsp/" />
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="app-pkg" />
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="messages" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="${struts.mode}" />
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="ihm,actions" />
<!--    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="" /> -->
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="10000000" />

<package name="app-pkg" extends="json-default,struts-default">

    <interceptors>

        <interceptor name="exception" 
          class="amundi.sits.myApp.web.utils.interceptor.ExceptionLoggingInterceptor" />

        <interceptor name="i18n"
          class="amundi.sits.myApp.web.utils.interceptor.I18nInterceptor" />                

        <!-- Basic Stack -->
        <interceptor-stack name="appBasicStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception">
                <param name="logEnabled">true</param>
                <param name="logLevel">ERROR</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare">
                <param name="excludeMethods">search*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
            <interceptor-ref name="multiselect" />
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>

        <interceptor-stack name="appStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="appBasicStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
            <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
        </interceptor-stack>

        <interceptor-stack name="annotatedStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
            <interceptor-ref name="annotationWorkflow" />
        </interceptor-stack>


        <!-- Stack basique qui priorise les params sur le prepare -->
        <interceptor-stack name="paramsFirstStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="exception">
                <param name="logEnabled">true</param>
                <param name="logLevel">ERROR</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams" />
        </interceptor-stack>

        <!-- Stack Json validation -->

        <interceptor-stack name="jsonValidationStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="appBasicStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidation" />
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
        </interceptor-stack>

    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="appStack" />

    <global-results>
        <result name="exception">/jsp/view/error/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="login" type="redirect">/Login.action</result>
        <result name="accessdenied" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">security/access/accessDenied.action</param>
            <param name="namespace">/</param>
        </result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Throwable"
            result="exception" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

</package>
```

Comment: It's unclear what are you doing. Are you using ajax or not?

Comment: No, in fact i tried to do it the "ajax" way (with the function i linked at the top of the question) but when the action method is finished, the page fall in error (no stack in either client/server console). I think it's due to mis-handling the returned outputStream to be downloaded as a file.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood that no output stream is returned.

Comment: Again there is no such type as none.

Comment: No outputstream is returned ?? what do you mean ??

Answer (score 0):

Well, the output stream should be returned by the result, but the action is mapped to the method `doExportExcel` with this annotation

```
@Action(value = "exportExcelMdt", results = {

        @Result(name = "exportExcel", 
                type = "stream", 
              params = { "inputName", "inputStream", 
                       "contentType", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
                "contentDisposition", "attachment;filename=${filename};", 
                        "bufferSize", "1024" }),

        @Result(name = "success", 
                type = ActionSupport.NONE) 
})
```

It has two results that the action can return, including global results, but the logic of the method implementing this action shows that in some cases it should return `SUCCESS` result. But this result has wrong type attribute value. Struts2 will confuse to execute this result, because it either not defined or not inherited. If you need to return `NONE` result you can do it in the action without overriding the action config with this result. Just return `NONE` because it's a global result.